# LIBOR Quoting Conventions and Swap Pricing

Tags: swaps, quantlib, libor

Given that LIBOR quotes have value date T+2, when considering a simple IRS, which dates are considered when fixing the floating rate? Say floating leg is Euribor 3M and next fixing date is today (02/12/2020), is the fixed rate set to the rate set today (which is essentially a 2 day forward rate)?

The reason I am asking this question is because when loading LIBOR fixings into a Quantlib IborIndex the fixing time series is shifted backwards by two days, that is when I upload fixing data from Bloomberg for date T, the time-series of the IborIndex lists this data under Date T-2.

Does the swap engine account for this "shift" in dates or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

In a vanilla swap, the first floating rate is in fact already known. So a swap today will have start date t+2 and todays fixing for the floating leg.

In QuantLib, when you supply a fixing, you have to supply the correct date, ie, 2 days before the accrual start (in the EUR case at least).

If you are estimating forwards, you would use the accrual start and end dates. The fixing at t-2 would be the relevant rate for that period.

Notice in this code, QuantLib will use the fixing for 02.12.2020 for the first period and not the fixing for 04.12.2020

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

yts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(2, ql.TARGET(), 0.05, ql.Actual360()))

tenor = ql.Period('2y')
index = ql.Euribor6M(yts)
index.clearFixings()
index.addFixing(ql.Date(2,12,2020), 0.02)
index.addFixing(ql.Date(4,12,2020), 0.066666)
fixedRate = 0.05
forwardStart = ql.Period("0D")

swap = ql.MakeVanillaSwap(tenor, index, fixedRate, forwardStart)
    
pd.DataFrame([{
    'fixingDate': cf.fixingDate().ISO(),
    'accrualStart': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
    'accrualEnd': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
    "paymentDate": cf.date().ISO(),
    'fixing/forward': cf.indexFixing(),
    'rate': cf.rate(),
    "amount": cf.amount()
} for cf in map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, swap.leg(1))])
```

[image]

Comment: Being pedantic, you only know the fixing if you trade after 11am (or whenever the fix arrives in your time zone)!

Comment: 10am in my time zone, but you are correct... If you trade before the fixing, the first rate on the floating rate will not be known